# Can I liquify/blend caramelized onions?

Tags: onions, blender

I will be making sausage and want to include the flavour of caramelized onions. I have caramelized the onions but the pieces seem a bit large to be in sausage.

I intend to add wine to the sausage as well. Can I simply liquify/blend the caramelized onions in a blender with some wine? Would this have any unintended or unwanted effects when introduced to a sausage mixture?

I could also run the caramelized onions through a meat grinder with the meat, but I am concerned the onions will be too "wet" and lead to a strange effect.

The recipe I am using is pretty simple. I am using garlic, salt, pepper, wine, and caramelized onion and I am making fresh sausages. I am worried that blending the caramelized onion will lead to an ugly brown in the sausage, but perhaps it is fine.

Comment: Without the recipe for the kind of sausage you're making it's hard to tell... Could you [edit] your question and include the recipe and ping me @Fabby

Comment: I'm with @Fabby - seeing the recipe would be useful; though I'd be tempted with just that small amount of information to say, wine & onion, blended, then fried off again to reduce moisture content.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's more of an answer than a comment, so I'll come back and upvote if you post that...  **0:-)**

Comment: @Fabby - Done, but it feels a bit short - though I can't really think of much else to add.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I added the recipe.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your recipe would be useful; though I'd be tempted that with just the small amount of information you provided that wine & onion, blended, then fried off again to reduce moisture content would be a solution to your problem.

Alternatively, bulk with breadcrumb, though I'd prefer the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

While you can certainly work with the carmelized onions, to avoid the issues you suggest I think I would be inclined to grate the onions or run them through a food processor first, and then carmelize them to a nice golden color.

Before adding them to the sausage mixture you may want to drain them on paper towels to avoid adding extra oil or moisture to the sausage mixture.

Comment: Thank you! I did end up cutting the onions pretty fine before caramelizing, and then I ground the onions with the meat and it turned out fine I think. I opted against blending the onions to avoid adding a "brown" liquid to the mixture and now instead of nice brown specks.